# How does Unity makes C# compileable to Android?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, game-development

The native language of Android is Java, and Unity uses C#, but there is still option to compile to Android. Godot also uses GDScript and source code of Godot is C++, but they still able to compile to Android with some unknown to me mechanics. How does it crossplatform like that and is there any tutorials for this?

Comment: Don't hold my word for it, but I suspect the C# to Android is using Xamarin. C++ just needs to be cross-compiled and linked to NDK.
So look into [The NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/), [Crosscompiling and toolchains](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain)

Comment: Also, the "native language" of android isn't Java but `anything that runs on the JVM`. The real native language of android will always be C/C++, regardless of the java/kotlin prefered external/framework trend.

Comment: I recommend that you learn about compilers, at least at a high level. This will help you understand how Unity can compile C# to something that can run on an Android device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 [Scripting Backends](https://docs.unity3d.com/2023.2/Documentation/Manual/scripting-backends.html) (at the time of this answer).

1. Mono2x   The standard Mono 2.6 runtime.
2. IL2CPP   Unity's .NET runtime.
3. WinRTDotNET  Microsoft's .NET runtime.

**IL2CPP**

Unity's scripting backend **IL2CPP** (Intermediate Language To C++) uses AOT compilation and supports many targets.  Not all targets support AOT (ahead of time) compilation.

> The IL2CPP backend converts MSIL (Microsoft Intermediate Language) code (for example, C# code in scripts) into C++ code, then uses the C++ code to create a native binary file (for example, .exe, .apk, or .xap) for your chosen platform.

You can read more about this here [IL2CPP Backend](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/IL2CPP.html).

The steps it takes (taken from the above link) are:

> 1. The Roslyn C# compiler compiles your application’s C# code and any required package code to .NET DLLs (managed assemblies).
> 2. Unity applies managed bytecode stripping. This step can significantly reduce the size of a built application.
> 3. The IL2CPP backend converts all managed assemblies into standard C++ code.
> 4. The C++ compiler compiles the generated C++ code and the runtime part of IL2CPP with a native platform compiler.
> 5. Unity creates either an executable file or a DLL, depending on the platform you target.

**Mono**

The Mono scripting backend uses JIT compilation.  Not all platforms support JIT (Just In Time) compilation.  Less information is provided in unitys documentation, though I suspect you can get the full details from the Mono documentation.

You can read more about this here [Mono Backend](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Mono.html)

If both scripting backends are supported, Mono is the default.
*Not sure if this is still the case, with the addition of WinRTDotNET, but I would assume so.*

**WinRTDotNET**

There is no information currently in unitys scripting backend documentation regarding WinRTDotNET.  This is the newest addition to the scripting backends.  Some information for Windows Realtime Support in IL2CPP can be found here [IL2CPP Windows Runtime Support](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/IL2CPP-WindowsRuntimeSupport.html)